# Не сохраняется ключ

Tags: git, source-tree, openssh

Удаленный репозиторий лежит на сервере компании. Подключение через OpenSSH. В SourceTree это есть, хотя я с трудом настроил. Но проблема в том что он не сохраняет информацию о ключе после закрытия. Т.е. я жму "Инструменты/Добавить ключ SSH", выбираю ключ-файл, появляется консолька с запросом passphrase, ввожу и можно пушить. Но вот как только закрываю клиент и потом опять нет доступа. Как сделать чтоб он помнил все?

Comment: *"потом опять нет доступа"* -- в чём именно это выражается?

Comment: @D-side в том что нельзя ни пул ни пуш сделать. Пишет что нет доступа.

Comment: думаю, надо расшифровать, как именно репозиторий лежит на сервере компании и как именно Вы к нему подключаетесь. Я могу придумать несколько извращенных способов, в которых вполне может наблюдаться Ваша ситуация, но они сильно извращенные:)

Comment: @KoVadim Я врятли смогу это описать. Я с огромным трудом настроил как-то чтобы работало, но как я это сделал я сам не понял. :D Раньше я работал только с репозиториями на гитхабе, битбакете и гитлабе. А тут просто реп лежит на том же серваке на котором сайты хостятся. Тупо это конечно, но не я придумал. Я только знаю что на нем CentOS. Я даже лазил туда по SSH.

Comment: И еще основная сложность настройки была в том что все клиенты гита требуют публичный ключ в обязательном порядке, но начальник дал мне приватный и сказал что нет никакого публичного и это все что нужно. Там правда еще был настроенный SmartGit в котором все нормально сохраняется, пушится и т.д. Но я не могу этим гавном пользоваться. Обычный консольный git for windows я кстати тоже так и не настроил потому что ему тоже надо публичный ключ, а его нет. В общем такой вот каламбур!

Comment: *все клиенты гита требуют публичный ключ в обязательном порядке* -- а вот и нет. Серверы требуют публичные ключи, чтобы опознавать подключающихся клиентов. Но клиенты используют соответствующие приватные ключи. Асимметричное шифрование позволяет не раскрывая приватного ключа дать возможность аутентифицироваться его владельцу. Да и в конечном счёте, публичный ключ можно сгенерировать из приватного, если вам очень нужно.

Comment: @D-side что "нет"? Если я вижу что в интерфейсе клиента пункт "публичный ключ" обязательный. Что тут "нет"? Нужен он ему или не нужен это вопрос десятый, но то что они требуют его в обязательном порядке - это факт. И как это можно сгенерить публичный ключ из приватного? С этого места поподробнее.

Comment: @DarkByte ну то, нет. Публичный ключ не позволяет аутентифицироваться по SSH, позволяет только приватный, публичный для них сам по себе бесполезен, требовать его нет никакого смысла. Не знаю, где вы видели это "обязательное поле". Сколькими клиентами пользовался, нигде подобного не видел. Можете продемонстрировать, как это выглядит у вас?

Comment: А вам не кажется, что если вы не разбираетесь сами и не понимаете -- то нужно просто обратиться за помощью к коллегам или эскалировать вверх? Вместо того, чтобы гадать с помощью хрустального шара, как принято в компании и что у вас не по инструкции сделано. Я слежу по работе за парой корпоративных git-серверов на базе Centos и там нечему просто ломаться. Не бойтесь сказать "я не понимаю" и получить шанс разобраться.

Comment: Пройдите в [webochat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50668/web), попробуем разобраться с вашим вопросом в режиме чата.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы установить ключ для работы вам надо пойти в **Options** (Настройки) и на вкдадке **General** задать значения для **SSH Client Configuration**:

- SSH Client: **OpenSSH**
- SSH Key: **<путь к файлу ключа>**

[image: настрой SourceTree]

Comment: Я так и делал .

Comment: @DarkByte Вы хотите не вводить пароль каждый раз при запуске программы?

Comment: Естественно. Зачем мне это?

Comment: Вы вводите пароль для расшифровки ключа. Не шифруте ключ, тогда ва не надо будет вводить пароль. А так, в любом случае при каждом запуске вам придеться его вводить.

Comment: Я не шифровал ключ. Не знаю о чем вы. Это же ключ, как его вообще зашифровать и зачем?

Comment: Вы имеет ввиду passphrase?

Comment: Файл id_rsa содержит приватный ключ для подписывания ваших данных, отправляемых на сервер. Публичным ключом, на сервере данные проверяют. Ознакомитесь с матчастью. Чтобы просто нельзя было украсть ваш ключ с компа, его шифруют, и расшифровывают только в памяти процесса. Но если вы считаете свой комп надёжным местом, то можете приватный ключ не шифровать. Да, `passphrase` для шифрование приватного ключа.